# Torch : How to select subset of tds data-structure?

Tags: torch

I am using the [tds data-structure](https://github.com/torch/tds) for some data manipulation purposes in Torch. I would like to know how can I select a subset of the value of this data structure.

eg. In Python,

```
> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
> a[1:3]
[2,3]
```

In Lua/Torch,

```
> a = torch.Tensor({1,2,3,4,5})
> a = [{{1,3}}]
1
2
3
```

What is the equivalent of the above operations in tds, if any?